# Find duplicate number in array and print the last duplicate number only

Tags: java, arrays, duplicates, numbers

We have to find the duplicate number present in an array 
But the trick is we have to print only the last duplicate number present in an array

Example
Input int[] a = {1,2,2,3,4,3,5}
Output = 3

Input int[] a = {2,2}
Output = 2

Comment: Ok, but where is your attempt? Are you expecting us to solve the homework for you? Sorry, but that is not how SO works.

Comment: First thing that springs to mind is you use a dictionary. Check each number in your array. If it doesn't exist in the dictionary, add it to the dictionary, if it does, set it to a variable. Print out the result of the variable.

Comment: Post your code please! It looks like you are asking us to solve this for you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks to be a homework question with no example of attempted solutions. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic number 3

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simple way is iterate and compare it. like below, I hope it may solve your problem

```
 int[] a = {1,2,2,3,4,3,5,5,7};
 String b = "";
 int count=0;
 for(int i = 0; i<a.length;i++){
     for(int j=0; j<a.length;j++){
         if(a[i]==a[j]){
             count++;
         }
     }
     if(count>1){
         count=0;
         b = String.valueOf(a[i]);
     }else{
         count = 0;
     }
 }
  System.out.println("last duplicate value : "
                       + b);
```

Java 8 feature same solution

```
String output="N/A";
              Integer[] a = {1,2,7,2,3,4,3,5,5,7};
               List<Integer> list= Arrays.asList(a);

              list= list.stream().map(m->m).sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()).collect(Collectors.toList());
              List<Integer> listSample=list;
               Optional<Integer> data = list.stream().filter(m->listSample.stream().filter(c->c==m).count()>1).findFirst();
              if(data.isPresent()) {
                  output=  data.get().toString();
              }
```

Comment: yeah it really solved my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Please review your question ( what do you mean by "last last duplicate and try it yourself first, just like @amongalen said, we're not here to solve your homework. We're more than happy to help you with more specific questions.)

If you are indeed trying to print the last duplicate value I would also suggest the dictionary.

Loop over the array and add the number to the dictionary if it has not been added before. If it has been added before then you should update a `currentDuplicate` variable. The `currentDuplicate` will always have the last duplicate value. After finishing the loop print out the `currentDuplicate`.

(I have not enough reputation to write this as a comment...)

Comment: i got your point thanks :